# using switch case for update MySQL query

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, mysql-python

Can you help me I wanna update my table by using switch case in MYSQL

```
 id value_s
 -------------
 1  one
 2  two
 3  third
14  fourteen
24  twenty-two
34  thirty-four
11  eleven
```

I wrote query but its issue :(

```
update t1
set value_s = 
   Case
     when id= 1
     then 'waroo'
     when id= 14
     then 'shanaaaaaaaaaaaaaaz'
   End ;
```

**Its my error:1175**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Error code 1175 is safe-updates error. It is an error protecting you from erasing your whole table by mistake. You need to add a where clause.

One solution is to turn off the safe mode, might be a good idea or not...

```
SET SQL_SAFE_UPDATES = 0;
```

Another simple solution is to just add a dummy where clause:

```
update t1
set value_s = 
   Case
     when id= 1
     then 'waroo'
     when id= 14
     then 'shanaaaaaaaaaaaaaaz'
   End where 1 = 1;
```